# Using rsync in a cronjob when a password is needed

Tags: shell-script, cron, rsync, password

Basically I have a bash script that fetches data from my server to perform a backup.

As it is now I have to start that script manually, enter the password, and then wait for it to finish.

I would like to set up a cronjob that handles the backup.

But I really don't know how to handle the password in a cronjob.

Also I can't use keys for this, because my provider does not provide the mechanisms I need to configure them.

I have SSH access to my home folder, but in my home folder I don't have write access except for the `http(s)docs` directory. So I can't create the necessary `~/.ssh/` directory and its contents for login via keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the command I use to backup to another machine:

```
rsync -av -e "ssh -i /root/ssh-rsync-valhalla-key" \
  --exclude lost+found \
  --delete-before \
  /mnt/backup/ \
  user@192.168.1.99:/cygdrive/r/\!Backups/Niflheim &
```

So you can use the `-i` to pass a keyfile to ssh. Of course, in your example, that means the keyfile itself will be sharable via HTTP if anybody ever figures out the filename.

Comment: So the path in the ssh command would be the path to the keyfiles on the remote? Since I dont use https on the server and it is deactivated I could then throw my keyfiles into httpsdocs and they would be safe there. I will give that a try in the evening.

Comment: No, the -i path is a local path. So he means run this in reverse; initiate the rsync from your server back to your home PC; 192.168.1.99 would be your IP.

Comment: What @Caesium said - this command pushes. You need to have `sshd` running on your home machine (along with firewall port forwarding, etc, etc). In my example, it pushes everything in `/mnt/backup/` to `R:\!Backups\Niflheim` on a Windows/Cygwin box @192.168.1.99.

Comment: The key file that `-i` specifies is the private key file... starts with `-----BEGIN DSA PRIVATE KEY-----`

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to start a daemon and keep it running? You could run `rsync` in daemon mode if so.

Then on the client you would connect with an `rsync://` url. For authorisation you could limit it to just your IP, I don't think there's an equivalent of SSH keys for it.

You need an rsyncd.conf, which can be anywhere, with something like:

```
[backup]
    path = /path/you/want/to/sync
    read only = true
    hosts allow = 1.2.3.4
```

Then start the daemon..

```
rsync --daemon --config=rsyncd.conf
```

And then you can try to sync from it:

```
rsync -av rsync://server.ip/backup /local/backup/dir
```

Comment: I cant run any additional demons, also I have a dynamic IP, so authorizing against it is not possible :(